# using structure definitions

Tags: function, scheme, racket

i've been pulling my hair trying to figure this out. i'm suppose to design a function takes in  a hstudent, i get another student with the same contents and  with his age converted into dog years. any ideas on how to start? This exact question is going to be on an open book test I have on Friday.

```
(define-struct hsstudent (first-name last-name classroom overall-grade age))

(define hsstudent1 (make-hsstudent "Randy" "Smith" 'WH '-A 14))
(define hsstudent2 (make-hsstudent "Jon" "James" 'AH '-A 13 ))
(define hsstudent3 (make-hsstudent "Alex" "Manzi" 'LO '+A 16))
(define hsstudent4 (make-hsstudent "Kevin" "Matthews" 'WH '-A 14))
(define hsstudent5 (make-hsstudent "Issac" "Lewis" 'AH '-A 13 ))
(define hsstudent6 (make-hsstudent "Michael" "Gabbin" 'LO '+A 16))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have the basic skeleton of the function you need to write? I'm not sure about your scheme/racket class, but when I helped teach a functional programming class, we stressed the idea of function "templates" over and over (and actually wouldn't give full credit if you weren't using them).

Answer (score 3):

Note: when you say *design*, that implies you're in a [HTDP-based](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/) course.

You should already have been introduced to a very concrete set of steps to follow for designing functions that consume and produce structures.  Have you looked at [Designing with Structures](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_one.html#%28part._sec~3adesignstructs%29) and followed the steps there?  If so, are you stuck at any particular step listed here?

The purpose of this methodology is to help pinpoint conceptual problems as soon as possible, rather than at coding time.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use the struct selectors to get the values from the student and then give those to make-hsstudent in order to make a new student. For example

```
(hsstudent-age hsstudent1)
```

Will return 14. Generally (hsstudent-FIELDNAME student) will give the field value of FIELDNAME for student.

Comment: so (define (student-new a)
  
( * 7 (hsstudent-age a) )) would give me the age in dog years. But how can I get a new student with similar contents?

Comment: How do you create a new student? You have some examples in your original question that create new students. Now you just have to incorporate the creation of a new student into the body of your function.

Comment: (define (student-new a b)
 (* 7 (hsstudent-age a)
    (hsstudent-first b ))) is what i've tried. bear with me, i just started learning about this topic this week.

Comment: @Josh: pay more attention to the *content* in Jen S's question.  Just repeating your prior answer isn't effective at all: it gives the impression that you're not listening, so then why should folks care to help then?  Jen is asking: how do you make a student?  If you don't know, please say so.